# Why ViewPagerAndroid rendered nothing within the ListView component?

Tags: android, listview, react-native

I'm rendering a ViewPagerAndroid in ListView.renderHeader(), but the elements under ViewPagerAndroid rendered nothing, is there anyone get the same issue like me?

[this issue on Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4455)

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderHeader={()=>{
            return (
                <ViewPagerAndroid style={{height: 150, backgroundColor: 'lightgreen'}}>

                    {/* ---- missed these things ---- */}
                    <View style={{height: 150, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
                        <Text>the View object is ok</Text>
                    </View>

                </ViewPagerAndroid>
            );
        }}
        renderRow={(d) => {
            return (
                <Text style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>{d}</Text>
            )
        }}
    />
</View>
```

[image: snapshot]

Comment: I also confused by this problem